# very noisy neighbor and need to record her rantings

Tags: microphone, noise

I have a very noisy neighbor and need to record her rantings - what microphone would be good for this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you gain access to their house through the loft? Get the mic as close as possible for the best quality recording is my advice.

Comment: If she's noisy enough, your cell phone should be able to make a recording with the built in mic. If you phone won't capture it, maybe she's not actually violating any local ordinances.

Comment: @ToddWilcox what kind of dB measurement is this , comment something useful.

Answer (score 2):

Basically any microphone should work if your neighbor is "very noisy".  If, in contrast, you are very nosy, a large diaphragm condenser (with suitable preamp/audio interface) or possibly a contact microphone on the wall/floor would do the trick.

Of course, operating non-trivial eavesdropping equipment on people not agreeing with a recording is illegal in most countries, so you might get into a whole lot of trouble by using equipment clearly intended to work for more than just recording an inordinate amount of noise.

In contrast, getting a loudness meter and recording or writing down its readings should be unproblematic.  If you want to bring civil suit, this will also have more evidentiary value than a voice recording which could really be from any actual loudness, depending on the quality of your equipment.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 options for what you want to do, and ill answer from sound perspective and not legal or w/e.

1st contact mic :You can attach a contact mic (piezo etc) on a wall and record it (if it comes from the hallway attach it to the door and so on)

2nd shotgun mic :If you have "visual" with the neighbor , e.g. he's on the other side of the road and most of the sound comes from a window , you should try a shotgun mic, pointing in that direction.

all these are from inside an appartment.

I dislike the condenser or "any" microphone as they are very generic and a car passing can easily make a recording useless.

Good Luck

Further example:

Comment: At least if you want to downvote explain why, it could make an answer better